# Mysql Comparison of 'WHERE' methods

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a difference between these two where clauses in terms of speed? Are the column still indexed in the second one?

```
1. SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE col1 = 'a' AND col2 = 'b' AND col3='c'

2. SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE (col1,col2,col3) = ('a','b','c')
```

When

```
PRIMARY KEY (col1,col2,col3)
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes, they're the same. The optimizer will rewrite the second form into the first before it's compiled.

Comment: @Mchl so I guess in that sense it is slower, but the difference speed would be insignificant.

Comment: Yeah. Parsing, compiling and actually running the query take each much more time, than this rewrite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There shouldn't be, but you can use EXPLAIN to find out in the context of your database.

Comment: Ok what does EXPLAIN do? and how do I use it. Edit: What difference would I see in the explain that would reflect the difference?

Comment: Type `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE col1 = 'a' AND col2 = 'b' AND col3='c'` and MySQL will give you information on exactly what plan it would use to answer your query.  Do the same for the other version of the query and, if the plan is the same, there's no difference in the execution strategies that MySQL would use.

Comment: Came out identical both ways I tried it. I'll leave the question open a it longer to see if anyone else has anything else to add. Thanks for introducing me to 'EXPLAIN'

Comment: There you go.  Should be no difference in the execution.

Answer (score 0):

Use `EXPLAIN` to determine the execution plan for the queries.

If `EXPLAIN` shows that they are the same, then the only time difference possible would be the parse time of the query string, which is insignificant compared to running the query.

Since you said `EXPLAIN` shows the same, just pick whichever one you prefer, it won't matter which you pick.

Answer (score 0):

You will get more information By using

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED
```